# Determining Span of a Set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine the span of the set {$(1,2,1),(-1,1,1),(2,1,0)$} in $\mathbb R^3$.

I have  <{$(1,2,1),(-1,1,1),(2,1,0)$}> $=$ {$(a-b+2c,2a+b+c,a+b | a,b,c \in \mathbb R)$}.

I believe this does not span the entire plane $\mathbb R^3$. How can I be sure of this though ? If it doesn't span the entire $\mathbb R^3$, I believe it only spans a certain plane in $\mathbb R^3$. How can I work out the equation of this plane ?

Comment: Use `$\langle \{ x\mid y\}\rangle$` for $\langle \{ x\mid y\}\rangle$.

Comment: Also, please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to prove such things is to write the vectors as rows in a 3 by 3 matrix and then row reduce it to RREF. If it reduces to the identity matrix, the vectors span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, if not, they will span a subspace equal to the number of pivots in the reduced matrix.

A way to see why this is the case, is that row operations on the matrix correspond to exactly what you would do when solving systems of linear equations.

Comment: Thank you. I did this and I obtained a row of zeros, so only 2 pivots. So what does this mean then geometrically

Comment: @NikitaMazepin this means that the vectors are not linearly independent of each other, and you don't span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, since there are two pivots your basis has dimensions of $2$

Comment: @wjmccann Okay I understand now. Thanks for your help. One last question, what does the span form geometrically ? It can either be a line or a plane right ? I am pretty sure it is just a plane and not a line.

Comment: If you, as in this example, have two linearly independt vectors, their span will be a plane going through the origin. A way to see this is to find a non zero vector $v$ perpendicular to both the spanning vectors. All linear combinations of your vectors will be perpendicular to $v$, so the span will have no "thickness" so to speak. Another way is to see that the parallelogram with your vectors as sides (and their sum and difference) is filled out by the span of your vectors. It can be tricky to see "why" it forms a plane, since mostly, a plane is simply defined by the linear span of two vectors

Answer (score 0):

The vector $(1,2,1)$ can be written as a linear combination of $(-1,1,1)$ and $(2,1,0)$. This implies that the set of vectors does not span $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: Why ? I know that means the $3$ vectors are not linearly independent I think.

Comment: Here is an intuitive way to think about it. Because the first vector can be written as a linear combination of the other 2 vectors, it lies in the plane formed by those other 2 vectors. So, because all three vectors lie along some plane, they are effectively trapped in that plane, and as a result they cannot cover all points in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: Okay I understand. Thanks. Say if I removed the vector $(1,2,1)$ and left the other two, this does not change the span right ? The other two vectors are linearly dependent. Would the span formed not change ?

Comment: That is right. Because the two remaining vectors are linearly independent, the span does not change. You can think of the vector (1, 2, 1) as a kind of redundant vector.

Comment: Okay perfect, I appreciate your help. So just to confirm, the span forms a plane that does not cover all of $\mathbb R^3$. If so, how can I work out the equation of this plane ?